# Social class in medieval Italian literature and its changes during the Renaissance

Tags: history-of-literature, historical-context, italian-language

I'm very interested in how notions of class were reflected in medieval Italian literature and how these archetypes, tropes, motifs or whatever you'd like to call them changed during the Renaissance with emergence of new ideas in Europe.

Can anyone give me a summary on this? Ideally based on good sources?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Your first question is a bit broad because this may have been different in various parts of Europe. Is there a specific country you are interested in? Your second question is a recommendation request, which is off topic here, so I will edit it out. Ideally, answers would cite sources and thereby indirectly provide the recommendations you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for narrowing the question down to Italian literature. However, I would recommend posting a separate question for the period Renaissance to Enlightenment, so this question covers the transition from the Middle Ages to the Renaissance.